# Get HTTP JSON PayLoad as POJO inside Interceptor class in JAXRS-2.0 application

Tags: rest, jax-rs, websphere, cxf, websphere-8

I am migrating from Apache Wink to Apache CXF 2.6.2. I have written following code to intercept the request:

```
@Provider
public class RequestInterceptor implements  ContainerRequestFilter{

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Context
    private ResourceContext resourceContext;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
      UriInfo info = requestContext.getUriInfo();
      System.out.println("URI path \"/" + info.getPath() + "\" invoked on " + info.getMatchedResources());
      requestContext.getRequest();

      RestfulInputBean bean = new RestfulInputBean();
      IRestPreProcessor preProcessor = (IRestPreProcessor)resourceContext.getResource(resourceInfo.getResourceClass());

      preProcessor.preResource(bean);   
    }
}
```

and following is my Resource Class:

```
@Provider
@Path("test")
public class AnotherRestfulResource implements IRestPreProcessor{

    public MyCustomObject preResource(RestfulInputBean bean){
        //code
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public RestfulResultBean test(UserDataBean dataBean){
        //My Code
    }

    public RestfulResultBean postTest(MyCustomObject assembly){
        //My Code
    }
}
```

When I am calling the service everything is working fine and `AnotherRestfulResource.test()` is getting called with the passed parameters (username and password in this case).

What  i want to do is, I want to read `UserDataBean` inside `RequestInterceptor` class because I want to do some processing.

In Apache Wink, I was doing it like this inside the Interceptor class inside  `handleRequest(MessageContext context, HandlersChain chain)` method like this:

```
SearchResult result = context.getAttribute(SearchResult.class);

RestfulInputBean inputBean=(RestfulInputBean)result.getInvocationParameters()[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you're looking for is a way to access the message body (pay load) itself. You can do so by calling [ContainerRequestContext#getEntityStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getEntityStream--)

Comment: Yes...I know about it...but if I read the entitystream in container request context then I am getting Exception in subsequent method chains which says EOF reached in stream. Secondly, I want the actual POJO. How can I get POJO from entitystream?